# BillingManager$6.run NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am using billing in my published app:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.2'
```

In the developer console, I see several crashes related to it. However, when I test it, it works as intended. The only message I can read from logs is:

```
NullPointerException
BillingManager$6.run
```

That's all. There is no trace, and not even Android versions displayed (yes, I have uploaded proguard obsfucation file to the console).

Does anyone know what it causes?